# Error message during the AVD starting process

Tags: android, android-emulator

I've created an AVD (version 2.2) using preferences set as default.

However everytime I start it I got error messages list below:

```
12-26 16:19:07.566: ERROR/Zygote(33): setreuid() failed. errno: 2
12-26 16:19:15.707: ERROR/Zygote(33): setreuid() failed. errno: 17
12-26 16:19:17.635: ERROR/BatteryService(87): usbOnlinePath not found
12-26 16:19:17.635: ERROR/BatteryService(87): batteryVoltagePath not found
12-26 16:19:17.645: ERROR/BatteryService(87): batteryTemperaturePath not found
12-26 16:19:17.695: ERROR/SurfaceFlinger(87): Couldn't open /sys/power/wait_for_fb_sleep or /sys/power/wait_for_fb_wake
12-26 16:19:48.305: ERROR/EventHub(87): could not get driver version for /dev/input/mouse0, Not a typewriter
12-26 16:19:48.305: ERROR/EventHub(87): could not get driver version for /dev/input/mice, Not a typewriter
12-26 16:19:48.495: ERROR/System(87): Failure starting core service
12-26 16:19:48.495: ERROR/System(87): java.lang.SecurityException
12-26 16:19:48.495: ERROR/System(87):     at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Native Method)
12-26 16:19:48.495: ERROR/System(87):     at android.os.ServiceManagerProxy.addService(ServiceManagerNative.java:146)
12-26 16:19:48.495: ERROR/System(87):     at android.os.ServiceManager.addService(ServiceManager.java:72)
12-26 16:19:48.495: ERROR/System(87):     at com.android.server.ServerThread.run(SystemServer.java:184)
12-26 16:19:49.675: ERROR/SoundPool(87): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
12-26 16:19:49.685: ERROR/SoundPool(87): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressStandard.ogg
12-26 16:19:49.705: ERROR/SoundPool(87): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressSpacebar.ogg
12-26 16:19:49.716: ERROR/SoundPool(87): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressDelete.ogg
12-26 16:19:49.725: ERROR/SoundPool(87): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressReturn.ogg
12-26 16:19:54.736: ERROR/ThrottleService(87): Could not open GPS configuration file /etc/gps.conf
12-26 16:19:54.836: ERROR/ThrottleService(87): Error reading data file
12-26 16:19:55.816: ERROR/logwrapper(186): executing /system/bin/tc failed: No such file or directory
12-26 16:19:55.916: ERROR/logwrapper(188): executing /system/bin/tc failed: No such file or directory
12-26 16:19:55.995: ERROR/logwrapper(190): executing /system/bin/tc failed: No such file or directory
12-26 16:20:02.135: ERROR/logwrapper(202): executing /system/bin/tc failed: No such file or directory
12-26 16:20:02.245: ERROR/logwrapper(203): executing /system/bin/tc failed: No such file or directory
12-26 16:20:02.295: ERROR/logwrapper(204): executing /system/bin/tc failed: No such file or directory
12-27 00:20:16.924: ERROR/HierarchicalStateMachine(87): TetherMaster - unhandledMessage: msg.what=3
12-27 00:20:17.174: ERROR/HierarchicalStateMachine(87): TetherMaster - unhandledMessage: msg.what=3
12-27 00:20:21.224: ERROR/HierarchicalStateMachine(87): TetherMaster - unhandledMessage: msg.what=3
12-27 00:20:47.534: ERROR/MetadataRetrieverClient(34): failed to extract an album art
12-27 00:21:24.814: ERROR/ThrottleService(87): Error reading data file
```

Please let me know how can I fix these errors. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you are experiencing actual problems, you can ignore error messages that occur during the startup of your emulator.

Comment: Yep, I found the apps are running smoothly. Thanks a lot.